# How to set the privacy of a video when uploading to vimeo?

Tags: laravel, vimeo

I'm using vimeo Api to upload video to vimeo. Video is getting uploaded but the privacy is locked how do i change that to anyone can video and embed ?
attached my code below

```
$video = $vimeo->upload($request->video, [
                    'name' => $request->title,
                    'description' => $request->description,
                    "privacy.view" => "anybody",
                    "privacy.embed" => "public",
                ]);
```

the above code is not working. what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

The API docs often use dot notation to represent a hierarchy of data, such as privacy.view. Since the PHP library sends all data using JSON, you must use nested associative arrays instead of dot notation.

```
// The documentation refers to the following as `privacy.view`
$params = ['privacy' => ['view' => 'disable']]
```

https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php